# Subdomain CNAME entry pointing to heroku still not available on some networks after 12 days. Is the NS record is wrong?

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain, cname, nameservers

I have developed an online store that needs to be added as a subdomain to the blog. I have added the domain on heroku and I did create 2 CNAME records 12 days ago:

```
sklep.justbeck.com.pl.      CNAME   justbeck.herokuapp.com. 
www.sklep.justbeck.com.pl.  CNAME   justbeck.herokuapp.com.
```

The site is available from some networks, but not all. In the begining I though it may be a DNS progapagtion taking slightly longer then usuall, but after 12 days the entries are still not available for most of the [whatismydns](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/sklep.justbeck.com.pl) servers.

I suspect that NS records may be messing with the subdomain:

```
justbeck.com.pl.    NS  ns3.netdc.pl.   
justbeck.com.pl.    NS  ns4.netdc.pl.
```

When I try to remove the NS records I get an error telling me that there must be NS entry.

What NS record should I create so the shop running on a heroku is accesible via a blog subdomain from all networks? Or is the problem somewhere else?

---

After doing some more investigation I found out that justbeck.com.pl has following servers listed as parent servers:

```
ns3.netdc.pl. [NO GLUE] [TTL=86400]
ns4.netdc.pl. [NO GLUE] [TTL=86400]
dns107.ovh.net. [NO GLUE] [TTL=86400]
ns107.ovh.net. [NO GLUE] [TTL=86400]
```

After I did nslookup for sklep.justbeck.com.pl on aformentioned name servers, the netdc respond with:

```
sklep.justbeck.com.pl   canonical name = justbeck.herokuapp.com.
```

While ovh servers respond with:

```
** server can't find sklep.justbeck.com.pl: NXDOMAIN
```

I am convinced now that the cause are the ovh servers. However I cannot remove ovh records since they are not the panel. How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

All [authoritative name servers](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/pl@8.8.8.8) for the .pl return 4 authoritative name servers for [justbeck.com.pl](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/justbeck.com.pl@a-dns.pl.) domain:

```
;QUESTION
justbeck.com.pl. IN NS
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
justbeck.com.pl. 86400 IN NS ns3.netdc.pl.
justbeck.com.pl. 86400 IN NS ns4.netdc.pl.
justbeck.com.pl. 86400 IN NS ns107.ovh.net.
justbeck.com.pl. 86400 IN NS dns107.ovh.net.
;ADDITIONAL
```

The first two look OK but `ns107.ovh.net` and `dns107.ovh.net` are missing [sklep.justbeck.com.pl](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/sklep.justbeck.com.pl@dns107.ovh.net) and [www.sklep.justbeck.com.pl](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/www.sklep.justbeck.com.pl@ns107.ovh.net) records (though they do resolve for example [www.justbeck.com.pl](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/www.justbeck.com.pl@dns107.ovh.net), but even for that name they give a differnet answer than [ns3.netdc.pl](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/www.justbeck.com.pl@ns3.netdc.pl) or [ns4.netdc.pl](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/www.justbeck.com.pl@ns4.netdc.pl))

If your domain control panel does not list those two domain servers, you should probably contact your domain registrar.